# Typo3: PersistenceManager persistAll() creates empty database record after add()ing object to repository

Tags: php, typo3-8.x

I'm trying to safe objects in my database therefore I'm using the PersistenceManager class.

Before calling `persistAll()` I'm adding an object to my repository.

```
    $newChecklist = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('foo\\bar\\Domain\\Model\\Checklist');
    $newChecklist->setNameDE('de');
    $newChecklist->setNameEN('en');
    $newChecklist->setAuthor('someGuy');
    //DebuggerUtility::var_dump($newChecklist); //returns object with correct attribute values
    $this->checklistRepository->add($newChecklist);
```

After that I'm using the PersistenceManager like this:

```
$persistenceManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Persistence\\Generic\\PersistenceManager');
$persistenceManager->persistAll();
```

But this code only produces an empty database record.

I can't find any errors in my syntax. The names of my files are all correctly set, Model=>Checklist, Repository=>ChecklistRepository,
Controller=>ChecklistController

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: your code looks correct and should work.
have you set a storgePid?

Comment: No I haven't. Where should I set it and what is it exactly that I have to set? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: In constants/setup plugin.tx_myextension_pi1.persistence.storagePid = 123

Comment: or maybe this post helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45051946/typo3-repository-add-not-works

Comment: I did that in the setup like this : 
`module.tx_extKeyHere.persistence.storagePid = {$module.tx_extKeyHere.persistence.storagePid}` 

and in the `Constants` file like this:

`module.tx_extKeyHere.persistence.storagePid=`

In another controller persisting objects that I have added to a different repository works fine. The code is the same.. I can't figure out why..

(To the other Post: I have seen that question but how would it help me? I'm already using the sledgehammer to persist my objects ;))

Comment: Oops, I'm wrong. if you have empty database entries, your object has been persisted. I think something is wrong with your object. what does the object look like in var_dump ()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works in my BE module:

```
class MyController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController
{
    /**
     * myRepository
     *
     * @var \VENDOR\Extension\Domain\Repository\AddressRepository
     * @inject
     */
    protected $addressRepository = null;

    function import() {
        $persistenceManager = $this->objectManager->get("TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Persistence\\Generic\\PersistenceManager");
        ...
        $record = GeneralUtility::makeInstance('VENDOR\\Extension\\Domain\\Model\\Address');
        $record->setTitle('The Title');
        $record->setPid(123);
        ...

        $this->myRepository->add($record);
        $persistenceManager->persistAll();
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I found my error. There were two different configurations for the Checklist TCA (I don't know why actually, this didn't happen under my watch ;)) I have deleted the wrong one and now everything works fine. Therefore one can say wrong TCA configuration can obviously cause Persistance errors!
Once again, thank you anyways!

Comment: No offend, but your commend does neither answer the question nor help anyone else what's the problem. You could have literally just replied "but it works on my machine". Please don't do that, this is not facebook. :3